# World of Warcraft party frames no longer automatically switching between profiles

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, I have 2 raid profiles created.

One is set to activate on 2, 3, and 5 player.

The other is set to activate on 10, 15, 25, and 40 players.

When I join a party, the number of players in the party does not matter and I need to manually go into the Raid Profiles interface to change the profile.

How do I fix this so **the raid profile is automatically changed upon joining a party?**

Comment: [seems to be broken](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/17622623242)